# totalCost = 0, what went wrong?

Tags: c#

The program runs fine but always return a zero value for totalCost.

Here is the code

```
double primaryCost = 0.0;
double totalCost = 0.0;
Console.WriteLine("Hello! Please enter the price of your first item for purchase:");
string item = Console.ReadLine();
double purchaseItem = Convert.ToDouble(item);
if (purchaseItem >= 50.0)
{
    primaryCost = (purchaseItem / 100.0) * 10.0;
}

Console.WriteLine("Do you have additional items for purchase? (yes/no)");
string answer = Console.ReadLine();

if (answer == "yes")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do you have additional items for purchase? (yes/no)");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter price for additional item: ");
    string additionalItem = Console.ReadLine();
    double secondaryItem = Convert.ToDouble(additionalItem);

    if (secondaryItem >= 50.00)
    {
        double secondaryCost = (secondaryItem / 100.0) * 10.0;
        double sum = secondaryCost + primaryCost;
        totalCost = sum;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("The cost of everything being purchased is: ");
Console.Write(totalCost);//Value comes up as zero. What is the issue?
Console.ReadKey();
```

Where did I go wrong? Was I not supposed to assign a default value of 0.0?

Comment: If you're not adding an additional item, totalCost will never be changed at all from the default value by your program.

Comment: As in any profession it is crucial to know how to use the tools of the trade. You have a debugger. Start to use it....

Comment: `totalCost = sum;` --> `totalCost += sum;`

Comment: while a debugger is nice.... You would be amazed to know how many people get into .net and c# with Noteppad++ and console commands.  Usually because they think it's the pro way to learn the language, or they think visual studio costs money (two free versions now days).

Comment: @Ryios Yes I tend to forget that

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the failed logic of how you are calculating your costs in general. For the code you have provided:

Add in:

```
if (purchaseItem >= 50.0)
{
    primaryCost = (purchaseItem / 100.0) * 10.0;
    totalCost = primaryCost;
}
```

You can get rid of primaryCost altogether.

```
// double primaryCost = 0.0;
double totalCost = 0.0;

double purchaseItem = Convert.ToDouble(item);
if (purchaseItem >= 50.0)
{
    totalCost = (purchaseItem / 100.0) * 10.0;
}
```

.../...

```
if (secondaryItem >= 50.00)
{
    double secondaryCost = (secondaryItem / 100.0) * 10.0;
    totalCost += secondaryCost;

}
```

Comment: I make the same comment on the now deleted post. What if the first item costs less that 50.0 and there is no second item? I would like to know the place where you could buy something that costs 60 and pay it 6, while at the same time for an item that costs 49 you pay 49. Oh well this logic seems to be screwed from the start.